BIM360 / ACC Webhooks event version.deleted?
I set up a webhooks for all data management events for a folder.
When I delete the file (as a user) I get an event with the following :
"hook": {
        "hookId": "9b4a8018-0bcd-some-numbers-7ff2452c806e",
        "tenant": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.0GGjDTycS3OD96-MDeznyQ",
        "callbackUrl": "https://webhooks.workato.com/someUrl/bim360",
        "createdBy": "rz66ZEJ7QN7D84b5UY99555t4lZHur9o",
        "event": "dm.version.added",
        "createdDate": "2024-05-26T14:00:47.504+00:00",
        "lastUpdatedDate": "2024-05-26T14:00:47.503+00:00",
        "system": "data",
        "creatorType": "Application",
        "status": "active",
        "scope": {
            "folder": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.0GGjDTycS3OD96-MDeznyQ"
        },
        ....
        ....
       "custom-metadata": {
            "dm_sys_id": "bd290a3c-1df7-4ad0-bef4-af28c75f89ab",
            "file_name": "A507.pdf",
            "lineageTitle": "",
            "forged.originalName": "A507.pdf",
            "dm_command:id": "1d722e66-127b-493f-a6a8-458b3b983701",
            "forge.type": "versions:autodesk.core:Deleted-1.0",
            "storm:entity-type": "SEED_FILE",
            "fileName": "6b2584e1-a126-4d63-a9c3-f4e6ef15fc92"
        }
       .....

I wonder if the dm.version.deleted ( as in here - https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/dm.version.deleted/) ever get triggered ?
There seem to be a lot of 'noise' when it comes to events - for example when I load a new file I get one dm.version.added event and several dm.version.modified fired immediately after , with custom properties change as the document becomes available.
Thanks , Jonathan

ACC/BIM360 only supports soft-delete, so there is no dm.version.deleted event support, as when we delete a file of ACC/BIM360, creating a new version with a version extension deleted is required like the below.
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer nFRJxzCD8OOUr7hzBwbr06D76zAT" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.cGVyc29uYWw6d2l/versions"
     -H 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json' -d '
 {
  "jsonapi":{
  "version":"1.0"
  },
 "data":{
  "type":"versions",
  "attributes":{
     "extension":{
        "type":"versions:autodesk.core:Deleted",
        "version":"1.0"
     }
  },
  "relationships":{
     "item":{
        "data":{
           "type":"items",
           "id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:hPW2BlBbQG2L5HjCOh7Z8Q"
        }
     }
    }
  }
}'

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/delete-and-restore-file/
